# How to retreive Id from the API

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am using java spring. So inside the database, I have the content table which have page Id column and content column. Inside this content column, there are many tracker Ids, saved as ContentJSON. I am trying to do the GET API using this url: localhost:8080/eHealth/api/user/mytracker/pageId?trackerId=2. However, it is showing the list of trackerIds under that specific pageIds.

My code is as follow:
//GET each tracker data

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @GetMapping(value = "/mytracker/{pageId}/{trackerId}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getTrackerContent(HttpServletRequest request, 
            @PathVariable String pageId, @PathVariable String trackerId) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        ValidationResult validationResult = this.tokenValidator.validateUserIdentityFromRequest(request);
        if(validationResult != ValidationResult.VALID_USER) {
            return this.tokenValidator.httpResponseEntityWithTemplateMessages(validationResult);
        }
        User currentUser = this.tokenValidator.getUserFromToken(this.tokenValidator.resolveToken(request));
        UserContent trackerContent = this.portalService.getUserContent(currentUser, pageId, "tracker");
        HashMap unpackedTrackerContent = this.unpackTrackerData(trackerContent);
        HashMap<String, Object> trackers = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        trackers.put(pageId,unpackedTrackerContent);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(trackers);     
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

The content column inside the database is as folows:

```
{"content":null,"UserContentJSON":"{\"trackerData\":[{\"trackerId\":\"1\",\"trackerDateTime\":\"05-07-2020T03:47:00.00Z\",\"trackerIntensity\":\"2\",\"trackerDuration\":\"1\"},{\"trackerId\":\"2\",\"trackerDateTime\":\"05-07-2020T03:47:00.00Z\",\"trackerIntensity\":\"2\",\"trackerDuration\":\"1\"},{\"trackerId\":\"3\",\"trackerDateTime\":\"05-07-2020T03:47:00.00Z\",\"trackerIntensity\":\"2\",\"trackerDuration\":\"1\"}]}","isNew":false,"ref":"tracker","programID":"HOPE_CVD_Copy","pageID":"physicalactivity","userID":"cvdtest"}
```

Answer (score 0):

"I am trying to do the GET API using this url: **localhost:8080/eHealth/api/user/mytracker/pageId?trackerId=2**. However, it is showing the list of trackerIds under that specific pageIds"

The controller expects 2 `@PathVariable` and not a `@RequestParam`

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/mytracker/{pageId}/{trackerId}")
public ResponseEntity<?> getTrackerContent(HttpServletRequest request, 
            @PathVariable String pageId, @PathVariable String trackerId) throws...{
```

So you should make a request like:  `localhost:8080/eHealth/api/user/mytracker/3/2` where *3* is the 'pageId' and *2* is the 'trackerId'

Comment: Hi. I changed it to this format but still the whole list of tracker Id came out. Is it because there is no tracker Id column but it only exist within the api?

Answer (score 0):

Like @Dirk said you made mistake in your `URL`.

Your `URL` should be something like this,

```
localhost:8080/eHealth/api/user/mytracker/{yourPageId}/{yourTrackerId}
```

That being said, in you implementation I don't see that variable `@PathVariable String trackerId` is used anywhere. You may need to check on that.

Comment: hello, yes you are right. I cannot use the trackerId inside the method because I don't have a separate column for tracker Id to retrieve from the database. I want to know is it possible to retrieve the tracker Id which is inside the content column as a json string?

Comment: @tracy Provide sample sample json string in your DB. Also mention what is your DB as well.

Comment: @tracy I assume this `getUserContent` is the method that you call to fetch data from DB. Need to change that as well. Therefore you need to provide current implementation of that as well

Comment: Please append these content to the question. So it will helpful for everyone

Comment: Hi @ray I moved it into the question :)